# traffic light color scheme or palette

Tags: r

I really like the Zissou1 palette from the wesanderson package (e.g. [here](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/top-r-color-palettes-to-know-for-great-data-visualization/)). It ranges from blue via yellow to red. Is someone aware of a color scheme that ranges from green via yellow to red? Can a wesanderson palette be adapted?

Comment: honestly - why the close votes. Surely this is a valid question!

Comment: No: A resource recommendation question is one that asks for a resource (which can be a book, website, or other resource) to learn a topic from. Surely I am asking for code to achieve scaled colors from green via yellow to red. I think SO people are far too hostile and trigger happy these days!

Comment: I'm happy to retract my close vote, but for me your question wasn't clear enough, it's more a resource request. Even the answer you got gives you a resources, but not a code.

Comment: A different question would have been to ask a way to "substitute" the blues in `Zissou1`  palette with greens. As stated, at the moment, this looks like off-topic. Which doesn't mean that it's bad or low quality, if it can be improved the votes can be removed.

Comment: @RLave I may be missing something but does: " Can a wesanderson palette be adapted?" not mean the same as: "way to "substitute" the blues in Zissou1 palette with greens"

Comment: @PoGibas maybe one should make the effort to try to understand the question first and not be so trigger happy?

Comment: I would try and re-phrase the question in order to make that point more clear then. Vote retracted, I'll let mods decide whether this is on topic or not.

Answer (score 0):

RdYlGn palette from RColorBrewer https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html